# Vuejs Routing Issue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have made a simple webpage in Vuejs format. I have a navigation tab in the header which includes tabs like (Markets, Sectors and Companies). There is a dropdown in each and every tab. I want to give a link in each and every dropdown tab. How should I route file or page from one tab to another?

```
export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'HelloWorld',
      component: HelloWorld
    },
    {
      path: '/MarketComponent',
      name: 'marketComponent',
      component: MarketComponent
    },
    {
      path: '/SectorComponent',
      name: 'sectorComponent',
      component: SectorComponent
    }
  ]
})
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use a router link:

```
<!-- literal string -->
<router-link to="/">go to Home World</router-link>

<!-- renders to -->
<a href="/">go to Home World</a>
```

If you outline a route in your router and then create your typical anchor tags as router links it will allow you to move routes using the router.

https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/router-link.html